# Android viewBinding is not binded some views in layout

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I have a problem with viewBinding. I use buildTools 28.0.3 and Android Studio 4.1.2

I have a layout with more than 50+ views. The binding class is generated normally but there are around 40 views that has been generated. I cannot figure out why the rest views are not generated. They are the same view's type as the generated views.

Anybody face this issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this issue. It's because I include "&" in layout file (even I put them in comment secion). I remove that character and re-build then everything is good.